# How to read emails from Clutter outlook folder C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I am trying to read the emails that are being moved to the clutter folder by outlook. The below code works fine for other folders, but when I try to open the clutter folder the code defaults to the error message indicate the folder does not exist.

```
oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
oNS = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace)oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
oNS.Logon(null, null, false, false);
oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

string folderName = "Clutter";
try
{
    oSubfolder = oFolder.Folders[folderName];

    for (int i = 1; i <= oSubfolder.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PostItem)oFolder.Items[i];

    }
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("There is no folder named " + folderName +
                ".", "Find Folder Name");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming Clutter is the child of the Inbox folder. It is Inbox's peer:

`oFolder = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Parent;`